# Hundreds of orange squares after appending object

Tags: append

This book has been sitting there in my scene for many weeks now, and suddenly all those orange squares have appeared below it. I opened a new file and appended the same book, and that does not happen there. It only happens when I append to this scene. Can you help me? A conflict must be going on of some kind.

Thank you[image]

Comment: That is a particle system, you must have changed the current frame